# Installing package that do not support .NetStandard

Tags: nuget-package, .net-standard

If a package is not supported by .NetStandard but the portable-net45 or netcore45. How can we install such package in .NetStandard targeting project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can install packages by using this small hack.

In project.json: in netstandard framework json. use imports key like below.

```
"frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.5": {}
  }


"frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.5": {
      "imports": "portable-net45+netcore45+wp8"
    }
  }
```